# How to get event name in called method

Tags: c#, events, reflection, types, delegates

I am using reflection to add an event handler to an event :

```
var eventInfo = type.GetEvent(eventName);
MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod", 
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var delegateForMethod = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, mi);
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, delegateForMethod);
```

This successfully calls my test method when the event occurs which is great, but now I need to know the name of the event that ended up calling this method...

```
void TestMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I know the sender, but which event was fired on the sender?
}
```

The reason I need this is because I have this generic register method which hooks up handlers to different types, and different events and channels them all to one method, while also making a note of what was attached. Once the test method fires, I need to pull out that note and use the info to notify the correct object that their "desired" event has fired. -- but to know this I need to know the event name as well as the type.

For example, in register I added Event A in type X for object O.... now when I see it triggered in the test method, I need to know it was Event A in type X, so I can notify object O by a certain interface method on it.

Comment: Why do you need to know, and what's the bigger picture here?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have to know it in the first place, but for the sake of it, look into the `StackTrace` class, see if you could find anything there.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Note that may not be an option, depending on the context.  A lot of events will fire the event handlers in another thread, which means a cleared stack trace.

Comment: If I were you, I would be listening to the different events with different methods, each calling to a generic method to handle the case if necessary, or simply have extra information in the arguments (inherit from `EventArgs`).

Comment: @YoryeNathan unfortunately I cannot mess with the source of the events, or change the arguments because they are in a different project and I want that project to be totally ignorant of what I am doing here.

Comment: It sounds like too much dependency, to allow ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem that canot be solved by introducing an additional level of abstraction!

Bind event like this:

```
obj.SomeEvent += (sender, args) => TestMethod("SomeEvent", sender, args);
```

or by reflection:

```
var eventInfo = type.GetEvent(eventName);
EventHandler delegateForMethod = (o, args) => TestMethod(eventInfo.Name, o, args);
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, delegateForMethod);
```

And in handler you can access event name from parameter:

```
void TestMethod(string eventName, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // eventName is event was fired on the sender
    TestMethod(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crazy thinking here.

To every event you are going to add `TestMethod`, `before TestMethod` you add an `anonimous method`, wich I will call `SetEventName` for understanding purposes.

That `SetEventName` just sets some `GlobalEventName` variable in your class taking `eventName`. (I suppose there's a way to use a lambda expression for that).

So, every time the event is fired. `SetEventName` is called.
Your `GlobalEventName` is set. Then `TestMethod` is called.
And inside `TestMethod`, use the `GlobalEventName` to do your job.

---

See an idea (sorry, I don't understand reflection quite well to put a ready-to-use code, but that's the idea)

```
var eventInfo = type.GetEvent(eventName);

Action<object, EventArgs> SetEventName = (Ob, Args) => GlobalEventName = eventName;
//I really don't know if it would work but....

Add that to the eventInfo before adding the TestMethod.

MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod", 
       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var delegateForMethod = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, mi);
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, delegateForMethod);
```

And your testmethod:

```
void TestMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Use the GlobalEventName to get event's name.
    // I know the sender, but which event was fired on the sender?
}
```